# Одновременная работа и обновление ListView

Tags: android, listview

Доброго времени суток, форумчане!

Создаю мобильное приложение в Android Studio. столкнулся с такой проблемой:

Принцип работы активности:

1. Отправляется POST запрос на сервер
2. Получаем обратно информацию в JSON формате
3. Обновляем полностью ListView

Нужно следующее:
Если я прокручиваю список ListView и останавливаюсь на середине списка, то при автоматическом обновлении ListView, я так же должен остаться на середине списка.

Реализовано:

```
//создаем адаптер и отправляем ему ArrayList(groups, locations) а так же context(PZakazi.this)
ExpListAdapter adapter = new ExpListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), groups, locations, PZakazi.this);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

//отключаем видимый Scroll
 listView.setScrollContainer(false);

//сохраняем положение ListView
Parcelable state = listView.onSaveInstanceState();

//обновляем ListView
listView.setAdapter(adapter);

//Восстанавливаем положение ListView
listView.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
```

Все работает замечательно! но есть НО!

Когда происходит ошибка?
Если запустить данную активность, и начать шевелить пальцем ListView туда<->сюда, быстро то выбивает следующую ошибку:

Ошибка:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. [in ListView(2131230815, class android.widget.ExpandableListView) with Adapter(class android.widget.ExpandableListConnector)]
```

Я приблизительно(на 80%) понимаю из-за чего это происходит, но не понимаю как именно исправить это..

Альтернатива:
Или возможно есть альтернативный способ обновить ListView, сохранив его позицию?

Очень нужна ваша помощь!

Comment: Вы обновление из какого потока ведёте?

Comment: Если не из UI потока, то определите в UI потоке Handler. После получения данных с сервера вызывайте этот handler, и в нём обновляйте адаптер.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[@Fabien](/users/20236/fabien) Вы создаете адаптер, потом notifyDataSetChanged, а потом устанавливаете этот адаптер ListView. Декларативно оно все верно, но вот только notifyDataSetChanged должен быть в самом конце. Данная ошибка возникает почти всегда, если кол-во элементов адаптера изменилось (по отношению к ListView. А присвоить адаптер, это почти всегда поменять кол-во элементов), а notifyDataSetChanged не был отправлен до того момента, когда ListView решил обновиться.

Comment: KoVadim, Спасибо тебе огромное!!!! поставил "notifyDataSetChanged" в самом конце, помогло!